# Diagonal search algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, diagonal

I am looking to implement a diagonal searching algorithm that is continuous. This means it is one long unbroken line that is going from the top of a MxN grid and then continuously iterating until the end without jumping to calculate each diagonal.

I have been trying to figure out this algorithm but I just don't see it. I will upload images of my work below. I am trying to write this algorithm in Java or C and then I will be converting it to MIPS. I am just having trouble trying to find the actual algorithm. [image: Image of the algorithm I am trying to implement]

Comment: The pattern of moves is E, SW, S, 2NE, E, 3SW, S, 4NE, E, 5SW, S, 6NE... until the diagonal.  You should spot the regularity. Past the diagonal, the pattern changes though with a similar principle.

Comment: The algorithm you already have (at least graphically), now just *convert* that to code (Hints: it will have to keep track of position [obviously] and maybe the direction [up-right or down-left; that can also be *calculated* based on position, but easier to just have a flag], and some checks on the borders)

Comment: Tip: Work with a 3x3 until you've got the code working... Number the cells 0 to 63. Notice the modulo possibilities? Diagonals "SW" increase cell ID by 7; diagonals "NE" decrease cell ID by 7. Coordinates can be derived from cell ID. Hit a boundary heading NE, if x++ overflows then do y++ instead; heading SW, if y++ overflows, then do x++ instead...

Comment: basic idea, simplified (for easier MIPS converting), must be completed for second *direction*:  `if ((x+y) % 2 == 0) { /*right-up*/ if (x < w-1) { x += 1; if (y > 0) y -= 1; } else { y += 1; } } else { /*left-down*/ . . . while (x != w-1 || y != h-1)`

Answer (score 3):

Continuing on @user85421's suggestion, in the map below the colors tell the direction to the next cell.

[image]

The checkerboard pattern (alternating yellow and green) is easily decided by testing the parity of x+y. Replacing yellow by red or green by blue on edges is straightforward, though there is a special case bottom left.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in C to calculate the `x` and `y` coordinates iteratively for a zigzag walk of the 2D array:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define M 10
#define N 8

int main(void) {
    int mat[M][N];

    for (int x = 0, y = 0, dx = 1, n = 0; n < M * N; n++) {
        mat[y][x] = n;
        x += dx;
        y -= dx;
        if (x == N) {
            /* exit to the right: go S then SW */
            x -= 1;
            y += 2;
            dx = -1;
        } else
        if (y < 0) {
            /* exit to the top: go E then SW */
            y += 1;
            dx = -1;
        } else
        if (y == M) {
            /* exit to the bottom: go E then NE */
            x += 2;
            y -= 1;
            dx = 1;
        } else
        if (x < 0) {
            /* exit to the left: go S then NE */
            x += 1;
            dx = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < M; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            printf(" %3d", mat[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
   0   1   5   6  14  15  27  28
   2   4   7  13  16  26  29  43
   3   8  12  17  25  30  42  44
   9  11  18  24  31  41  45  58
  10  19  23  32  40  46  57  59
  20  22  33  39  47  56  60  69
  21  34  38  48  55  61  68  70
  35  37  49  54  62  67  71  76
  36  50  53  63  66  72  75  77
  51  52  64  65  73  74  78  79
```

Here is an alternative without an extra variable, using the parity of `x + y`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M 10
#define N 8

int main(void) {
    int mat[M][N];

    for (int x = 0, y = 0, n = 0; n < M * N; n++) {
        mat[y][x] = n;
        if ((x + y) & 1) {
            if (y == M - 1) {
                /* exit to the bottom: go E */
                x += 1;
            } else
            if (x == 0) {
                /* exit to the left: go S */
                y += 1;
            } else {
                /* follow the NE diagonal */
                x -= 1;
                y += 1;
            }
        } else {
            if (x == N - 1) {
                /* exit to the right: go S */
                y += 1;
            } else
            if (y == 0) {
                /* exit to the top: go E */
                x += 1;
            } else {
                /* follow the NE diagonal */
                x += 1;
                y -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < M; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            printf(" %3d", mat[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `x+y` is constant along each diagonal, I would do it like this:

```java
// x+y is constant along each diagonal
for (int sumxy = 0; sumxy < M+N-1; ++sumxy) {
  // determine the range of y-x
  // 2x = sumxy-diffyx => 0 <= sumxy-diffyx <= 2M-2 => sumxy-2M+2 <= diffyx <= sumxy
  // 2y = sumxy+diffyx => 0 <= sumxy+diffyx <= 2N-2 => -sumxy <= diffyx <= 2N-2-sumxy
  int mindiff = max(sumxy-2*M+2, -sumxy);
  int maxdiff = min(sumxy, 2*N-2-sumxy);
  for (int d=0; d <= maxdiff-mindiff; d+=2) {
    // odd sum => increasing diff, even sum => decreasing
    int diffyx = (sumxy & 1) ? mindiff + d : maxdiff - d;
    int x = (sumxy-diffyx) >> 1;
    int y = (sumxy+diffyx) >> 1;
    // process (x,y)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the algorithm can be described as:

1. Move 1 step right. If not possible move 1 step down. If not possible goto 6.
2. Move diagonal down-left as long as possible. If not possible at all goto 6.
3. Move 1 step down. If not possible move 1 step right. If not possible goto 6.
4. Move diagonal right-up as long as possible. If not possible at all goto 6.
5. Goto step 1.
6. Done, i.e. all elements have been visited

Comment: that is: 1:right, 2:down-left; 5: *back to step 1*; 1:right  ??

Comment: @user85421 I don't really understand your comment. The first is: right, down-left, down, up-right, .... The steps above should give that. The "complicated" thing is to cover both even and odd dimensions.

Comment: the "we are done" is confusing me - does that mean go to next step? (shouldn't that be the default?)

Comment: @user85421 The "we are done" is supposed to mean: We have visited all elements so the program/loop can stop